# Converting GDELT to Turtle Triples

Tags: uri, turtle-rdf

I want to convert GDELT events to turtle triples.
Is there a standard for making URIs for instances?
Can I just make one up? Something like

```
http://www.gdeltproject.org/Events/1.0/GDELTEventID_674976286
```

perhaps?

Comment: Looks OK, though non-dereferenceable... Probably you know: https://www.w3.org/TR/cooluris/